# SAP MDG see Change Documents of a given Business Partner?

Tags: sap-erp, master-data-management

I would like to know if there's a way or some query to see the Change Documents out of a given Business Partner using SAP or SAP Webdynpro GUI. I've googled but tables such as CDHDR or CDPOS are not working for me. Any other thoughts?

Comment: they are not working because probably change docs are not enabled on your system, so there is no query that can help you

Comment: When I enter to a Change Request through MDG I can see a button that says 'Change Documents' and when I click it I can access and see all the changes that have been made to that code. I would like to know if there's something like: https://<domain>/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/USMD_CHANGE_DOCUMENT=<requestID> so I can access directly through the link to see those changes instead of opening the change request and then opening the change documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check and enable (if they were disabled) the change document object BUPA_BUP in SCDO transaction, with the following values

[image]

Check this mini-guide: http://abapcadabra.com/index.php/cookies/541-change-documents

Comment: Well, that's a good start. Thank you for the link, it has a clear explaination. However, I know there's an object called 'USMD_CHANGE_REQUEST' that shows change requests in MDG, right? Can I pass values to that object like a method? EX: <link>/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/USMD_CHANGE_REQUEST=<changeRequestId>
I would like to access directly to the change documents of a specific change request through a link. Or are there any tables where those change documents are saved? Are there any table where notes or attachments are saved aswell? That's something that would be of much help to know. Thank you!